# Relative module references

Tags: scala, sbt

I have multimodule sbt (0.13.2) project

```
foo
 - foo-api
 - foo-web
 - ...
```

`foo` and each subdirectory has `build.sbt`.

Toplevel file is just an aggregator:

```
lazy val fooApi = Project("foo-api", file("foo-api"))
lazy val fooWeb = Project("foo-web", file("foo-web")).dependsOn(fooApi)
// ...
lazy val foo = Project("foo", file(".")).
  aggregate(fooApi, fooWeb, ...)
```

Now I absolutely need (not my choice) to be able to compile `foo-web` separately from **inside** `foo-web` subdirectory and it should still depend on `foo-api`.

I endend up adding following fragment to `foo-web/build.sbt`:

```
lazy val fooWeb = Project(id = "foo-web", base = file("."))
  .in(file("."))
  .dependsOn(Project("foo-api", file("../foo-api"))
```

Which works for `cd $root/foo-web && play compile` but now breaks `cd $root && play compile` since relative paths are relative to execution directory.

How can I reference project using relative path that works regardless of which directory sbt command was executed in ?